# Открыть приложение Windows Apps по ссылке

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно, вопрос в теме: как открыть ссылку внутри приложения, которое располагается в директории WindowsApps? Предложенные поисковиком ответы только ещё больше запутали.

Comment: `по ссылке` пример есть?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 2):

По сути, есть 2 способа запуска:

1. Уникальная ссылка:
   Суть в том, что почти все (а может и все) приложения регистрируют в системе свою уникальную ссылку формата `name://`, открыв ее откроется и самое приложение.

   - Идем в реестр по пути `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\(уникальный id)\ActivatableClassId\(уникальный id)\CustomProperties`
   - Смотрим значение `Name`
   - Пробуем открыть, например у Яндекс.Музыка будет `yandexmusic://`
2. По уникальному идентификатору:
   Честно, я без понятия, где лучше его искать, в реестре каша, а вот виртуальная папка `AppsFolder` (открыть в проводнике можно через `shell:AppsFolder`) содержит в себе все нужное сразу, программно открывать виртуальные директории весьма геморно, но для этого есть официальная библиотека от Microsoft [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/)

   - Ставим указанный выше пакет через NuGet
   - Далее пишем:

     ```
     var appsFolder = KnownFolderHelper.FromKnownFolderId(new("1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58"));
     ```

     Значение `1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58` - это `Guid` нужной папки, который можно посмотреть [в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid).
   - Получив доступ к директории, мы можем уже баловаться как хотим

     - Например, пройтись циклом и вывести имена приложений:

       ```
        foreach (var app in appsFolder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
        }
       ```
     - Или, зная то, что Windows приложения заканчиваются на `!App`, получить их все

       ```
       var winApps = appsFolder.Where(x => x.ParsingName.EndsWith("!App"))?.ToArray();
       ```
     - Ну или найти конкретное приложение, например, по названию

       ```
       var yaMusic = appsFolder.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Яндекс.Музыка");
       ```

     Умея все это, мы теперь можем вытянуть нужный нам идентификатор приложения. За это отвечает свойство `ParsingName`, которое и является идентификатором для создания ярлыка.
   - Имея нужный нам идентификатор, мы можем запустить приложение, делается это очень просто:

     ```
     Process.Start("explorer.exe", $@"shell:appsFolder\{yaMusic .ParsingName}");
     ```

Вот вроде 2 основных способа запуска таких приложений, выбирайте нужный и используйте. Способ с идентификатором я лишь показал для "автоматизации", вы можете его найти руками написав `shell:AppsFolder`, в открывшейся папке найти нужное приложение - ПКМ - создать ярлык, на рабочем столе заходим в свойства ярлыка и там будет идентификатор, через него и запускайте, сам он воде уникальный и не меняется при обновлениях.